# For loops wont stop

Tags: java, android, for-loop

2 part question here. I'm having some trouble here with my for loops. The basic idea of my code is that whenever checkX and checkY are called they compare the x of the touch and the x of the player then if the players x is less than the touchx then it increments the player x by 1 until the player x equals touch x. Its the exact same thing for checky. Everything works fine, the problem is that it never stops. The player just keeps moving on the exact same path.

Heres the player class

```
package com.gametest;

import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

import com.gametest.GameSurfaceView.MyView;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;

public class Player {
    int ID;
    static int x, y, width, height, widthEnd, currentFrame, boundsX, boundsY,
            dirTimer, dir, simx, simy;
    static Bitmap currentSprite, playerSprite, deathSprite;
    static MyView mv;

    public Player(MyView v, Bitmap orb, Bitmap explosion, int screenWidth,
            int screenHeight) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        playerSprite = orb;
        deathSprite = explosion;
        currentSprite = playerSprite;
        mv = v;
        height = playerSprite.getHeight();
        width = playerSprite.getWidth() / 3;
        currentFrame = 1;

    }

    public static void sprite_draw(Canvas canvas,
            CopyOnWriteArrayList<Sprite> copy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x = (mv.getWidth() / 2) - 50;
        y = (mv.getHeight() / 2) - 50;
        currentFrame = currentFrame + 1;
        if (currentFrame > 3) {
            currentFrame = 1;
        }
        widthEnd = (currentFrame * width) + width;
        boundsX = x + width;
        boundsY = y + height;
        Rect src = new Rect(currentFrame * width, 0, widthEnd, height);
        Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, boundsX, boundsY);
        canvas.drawBitmap(currentSprite, src, dst, null);
        for (Sprite s : copy) {
            if (s.x + 50 > x && s.x + 50 < boundsX && s.y + 50 > y
                    && s.y + 50 < boundsY) {
                GameSurfaceView.damagePlayer();
            };
        }

    }

    public void checkX(Integer touchx) {
        if (touchx > x) {
            for (int newx = x; newx < touchx; newx++) {
                GameSurfaceView.setDirection(1, 0);
                try {
                    mv.t.sleep (10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        if (touchx < x ) {
            for (int newx = x; newx > touchx; newx--) {
                GameSurfaceView.setDirection(-1, 0);
                try {
                    mv.t.sleep (10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkY(int touchy) {
        if (touchy > y) {
            for (int newy = y; newy < touchy; newy++) {
                GameSurfaceView.setDirection(0, 1);
                try {
                    mv.t.sleep (10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        if (touchy < y) {
            for (int newy = y; newy > touchy; newy--) {
                GameSurfaceView.setDirection(0, -1);
                try {
                    mv.t.sleep (10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in case its needed here is the surface view class

```
package com.gametest;

import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class GameSurfaceView extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    double ran;
    int touchX, touchY, screenWidth, screenHeight, objX, objY;
    static boolean canUpdate;
    static int enemyCount, score, playerHealth, test1, test2;
    static MyView v;
    static Bitmap orb, orb2, explosion;
    static CopyOnWriteArrayList<Sprite> copy = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Sprite>();
    static String hpString;
    static Player player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        v = new MyView(this);
        v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
                touchX = (int) me.getX();
                touchY = (int) me.getY();
                for (Sprite sprite : copy) {
                    sprite.checkTouch(touchX, touchY);
                    player.checkY(touchY);
                    player.checkX(touchX);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        canUpdate = true;
        screenWidth = v.getWidth();
        screenHeight = v.getHeight();
        playerHealth = 250;
        hpString = "Health " + playerHealth;
        ran = 0;
        score = 0;
        test1 = 5000;
        test2 = 5000;
        orb = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blue_orb);
        orb2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red_orb);
        explosion = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.explosion);
        player = new Player(v, orb2, explosion, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        createEnemies();
        setContentView(v);

    }



    private void createEnemies() {
        if (enemyCount < 5) {
            screenWidth = v.getWidth();
            screenHeight = v.getHeight();
            int listLength = copy.size();
            copy.add(new Sprite(v, orb, explosion, screenWidth, screenHeight, listLength));
            enemyCount = enemyCount + 1;
        }
    }

    public static void checkECount(int id) {
        canUpdate = false;
        copy.remove(id);
        enemyCount = enemyCount - 1;
        int index = 0;
        for(Sprite s : copy) {
              s.ID = index;
              index++; 
            }
        score = score + 10;
        canUpdate = true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        v.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        v.resume();
    }

    public class MyView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        Thread t = null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean isItOk = false;

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            holder = getHolder();

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isItOk == true) {
                if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
                    if(canUpdate){
                        canvas_draw(c);
                    }
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                try {
                    t.sleep (50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

        }

        protected void canvas_draw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawARGB(255, 50, 10, 10);
            String ranString = "Score " + score;
            ran = Math.random() * 5;
            String t = "max1" + test1;
            String t2 = "max2" + test2;
            if (ran > 3) {
                createEnemies();
            }
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize(15);
            canvas.drawText(hpString, 10, 25, paint);
            canvas.drawText(ranString, 10, screenHeight - 25, paint);

            for (Sprite sprite : copy) {
                sprite.sprite_draw(canvas);
            }
            Player.sprite_draw(canvas, copy);

        }

        public void pause() {
            isItOk = false;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    t.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
                break;
            }
            t = null;
        }

        public void resume() {
            isItOk = true;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        return false;
    }

    public static void damagePlayer() {
        hpString = "Health " + playerHealth;
        playerHealth = playerHealth - 5;
        if(playerHealth<0){
            hpString = "game over";
        }
    }



    public static void setDirection(int i, int j) {
            if(i == 0 && j == -1){
                for(Sprite s: copy){
                    s.y++;
                }
            }
            if(i == 0 && j == 1){
                for(Sprite s: copy){
                    s.y--;
                    }
            }
            if(i == -1 && j == 0){
                for(Sprite s: copy){
                    s.x++;
                }
            }
            if(i == 1 && j == 0){
                for(Sprite s: copy){
                    s.x--;
                    }
            }

        }

    }
```

So the first part of my question is can anyone tell me why the for loops wont stop looping. And the second part of my question is how can I force the checkX and checkY methods to restart if the player selects a different point before he makes it to the first location.

Comment: Which loop won't stop? What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: Within the loops, you're sure that `x` and `y` are numbers (rather than null or NaN or something)? I don't know what order those are set in.

Comment: X and y are definitely getting set.

Answer (score 1):

Check and see if your problem lies with your signature in your checkX and checkY functions. `Integer` is a class, and `int` is a primitive type, so you can't do something like `Integer n = 1`, but you can do `int n = 1`.

```
public void checkX(int touchx)
public void checkY(int touchx)
```

Comment: Can you step through a debugger and see the values of `touchx`, `touchy`, `x`, and `y`? That could also be your problem, as the loop can only exit when the condition is no longer met.

Comment: touchx and touchy are fine but something is resetting newx and newy right before the loop is supposed to stop. Can anyone see what it is?

Comment: I am not 100% familiar with Android development, but perhaps there is an issue with your touch handler? Maybe it is registering multiple touches and creating some sort of race condition where newX and newY are affected? Try debugging without using the touch handler and see what happens.

Comment: touchx and touchy are completely fine, Im drawing all of the values to the screen constantly, thats how I know for sure that its newx and  newy getting reset right before they make it to touchx and touchy.

Comment: So have you stepped through a debugger yet?

Comment: I'm kinda new to java so I dont know how to do that yet.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse as an IDE? If you are, you should be able to either right click a line and set a breakpoint, or click to the left of the line to set one. If you are not using Eclipse, you should read up on debugging for your IDE. Once you set a breakpoint in the `checkX/Y` loop, you will be able to see the values of your relevant variables.

Comment: Try placing a breakpoint inside one or all of the 4 `for` loops in your `touchX` and `touchY` functions. If you are using Eclipse, the run with debugging button looks like a bug. Once it hits the breakpoint, you can view the variables and their values.

Comment: I still don't understand what I'm looking for. If its just to see my variables they get drawn to the screen right now so I can see them from there.

Comment: You are looking for the exact moment where newX 'resets', and why that is happening. Even though it looks good in your application, that doesn't mean everything is good in the backend.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all of your help. I cant find it right now but I'll check back again in a couple of days if I find it or I still need help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, I think you'll find your answer if you use the debugger to step through line by line until you find the problem. Good luck!